# CSS Animation does not start working when open page

Tags: html, css, animation

What i am trying to do is when someone open the page, a 10px line turns into 85px in 10 second but when i open it, it's already a 85px line and nothing happens. What are my mistake? here's my code:

```
@keyframes linee{
0%{width:10px;}
100%{width:85px;}
animation-duration:10s;
animation-fillmode:forwards;}
.line{
border-bottom: 3px solid #32ff7e;
animation-name: linee;
border-radius: 50px; }
```

and the html code is

```
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: your code is *scrambled*, you have declaration that are outside the class, move them inside

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You had several syntax errors. Here a corrected version:

```css
@keyframes linee{
  0% { width:10px;}
  100%{ width:85px;}
}

.line{
  border-bottom: 3px solid #32ff7e;
  animation-name: linee;
  border-radius: 50px; 
  animation-duration:10s;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: `animation-duration:10s;` and `animation-fillmode:forwards;` were outside the brackets of your element *.line*. In `animation-fill-mode` there was a dash missing .

Answer (score 0):

Run this code. Your issue is resolved.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <style>
    .line {
      border-bottom: 3px solid #32ff7e;
      border-radius: 50px;
      animation-name: linee;
      animation-duration: 10s;
    }
    
    @keyframes linee {
      0% {
        width: 10px;
      }
      100% {
        width: 85px;
      }
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="line">Line</div>

</body>

</html>
```